# Maven plugin for eclipse not found

Tags: linux, eclipse, maven, ubuntu-12.04, nutch

Trying to run nutch on eclipse. I following [this guide](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/RunNutchInEclipse) but i could not install maven plugin for eclipse. [Maven plugin for eclipse](http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/) seems not available. How can i install m2e plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/ as an update site inside eclipse? Doing that should enable you to download it.